# Отобрать статистически значимое количество значений в группе в датафрейме

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
data = {'id_поставки': ['101','102','103','250','255','260','290','0112', '7011', '0151','06611', '600', '56','96', '59', '235', '785'],
'месяц_поставки': ['январь','март','январь','март', 'сентябрь','март','март', 'март', 'ноябрь', 'январь','январь', 'март', 'январь','июль', 'март', 'март', 'апрель']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id_поставки', 'месяц_поставки'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В котором есть id поставки и месяц поставки.

Нужно получить датафрейм, в котором для каждого месяца будет статистически значимое количество число строк из `dates`.

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для вычисления статистически значимого числа поставок для каждого месяца используется функция `sample_size`

```
def sample_size(population_size, confidence_level=90, confidence_interval=50):
    confidence_level_constants = {
        50: 0.67,
        68: 0.99,
        90: 1.64,
        95: 1.96,
        99: 2.57
    }
    p = 0.5
    e = confidence_interval / 100.0
    N = population_size
    n_0 = 0.0
    n = 0.0
    Z = confidence_level_constants[confidence_level]
    n_0 = ((Z**2) * p * (1-p)) / (e**2)
    n = n_0 / (1 + ((n_0 - 1) / float(N)) )
    return int(math.ceil(n))
```

Вычислить необходимый размер выборки для каждого месяца можно, применив `sample_size` к колонке id_поставки при группировке: `data.groupby('месяц_поставки',as_index=False).agg({'id_поставки':'count'})`

Как получить таблицу из ожидаемого результата?

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать, в чём у вас сложность?

Comment: Пытался найти функцию, которая на вход принимает число (в моем случае это кол-во уникальных поставок за конкретный месяц), точность и погрешность, и на выходе отдает кол-во стат значимой выборки. Не понимаю какие методы мне могут помочь, поиск в гугл не дал как такового результата

Comment: Понятно, вопрос скорее про статистику, а не про Pandas, я в статистике не настолько силён.

Comment: А что за термин такой "статистически значимое количество поставок"?  Определение из Википедии: "В статистике величину переменной называют статисти́чески зна́чимой, если мала вероятность случайного возникновения этой или ещё более крайних величин. Здесь под крайностью понимается степень отклонения тестовой статистики от нуль-гипотезы". Это понятно. А что такое "статистически значимая ВЫБОРКА"? Да еще и за каждый месяц отдельная?

Comment: @passant нужно рассчитать размер выборки, при которой мы получим стат значимый результат, т.е. понять при каком кол-ве выборка будет репрезентативной

Comment: @formanite Что-бы получить "статистически значимый результат", вам надо для начала определить, о какой статистике идет речь. Вычисление среднего? Вычисление среднеквадратичного отклонения? Вычисление  медианы?  Давайте все-таки оперировать традиционными терминами, принятыми в статистике.  Например: "какой минимальный объем выборки необходим для того, чтобы оценка ( например выборочное среднее арифметическое ) отличалась от истинного значения среднего значения генеральной совокупности не более чем на заданную величину? " Что бы все все понимали однозначно.

Comment: @passant извините, буду точнее в формулировках. Тем временем я добавил функцию, которая принимает на вход размер генеральной совокупности , точность и погрешность, а на выходе мин. объем выборки. Подскажиет пожалуйста как можно применить эту функцию , чтобы получить ожидаемый датафрейм

Comment: @formanite как связана таблица "Ожидаемый результат" с таблицей "фрейм данных"? В ожидаемом результате первой строкой идёт апрель, которого нет в исходных данных. Какой смысл имеет `id_поставки` в ожидаемом результате?

Comment: @PakUula перепутал скриншоты, данные в коде указаны верно, скриншот заменил

Comment: @formanite по-прежнему неясно, что такое "ожидаемый результат" и какой смысл у id поставки. Из общих соображений, где-то в результате должны присутствовать доверительный уровень и число поставок.

Comment: @PakUula ожидаемый результат - это результат применения функции sample_size. Сначала я получаю датафрейм с числом минимального объема выборки: dates.groupby('месяц',as_index=False).agg({'id_поставки':'count'})['id_поставки'].apply(sample_size) , а далее нужно используя полученные значения минимального объема (количество уникальных поставок по каждому месяцу) отобрать такое количество в исходном датафрейме. В результате здесь доверительный интервал не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас уже почти всё готово.

Сначала нужно сделать серию с необходимым числом поставок для каждого месяца:

```
month_size = dates.groupby('месяц_поставки')\
    .count()['id_поставки']\
    .apply(sample_size)
```

Результат

```
месяц_поставки
апрель      1
июль        1
март        3
ноябрь      1
сентябрь    1
январь      3
```

Дальше просто. Нужно выбрать из `dates` нужное число строк из каждого месяца и собрать их в один фрейм.

Выборка строк. Для примера возьмём январь:

```
m = 'январь'
dates[dates['месяц_поставки'] == m][:month_size[m]]
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Склеивание в один фрейм: `pd.concat`

Итого:

```
pd.concat([
    dates[dates['месяц_поставки'] == m][:month_size[m]]  
    for m in month_size.index
])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вам нужно, чтобы нумерация строк была с нуля, то добавьте вызов метода `reset_index`:

```
pd.concat([
    dates[dates['месяц_поставки'] == m][:month_size[m]]  
    for m in month_size.index
]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает